# why template operator overloading doesn't work?

Tags: c++, templates

Why doesn't this code print "operator="?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    template<typename T> void operator=(const T& other){
        cout<<"operator="<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a;
    A b;
    a=b;
}
```

Comment: Because it's merely an assignment operator, and so does not prevent the compiler from implicitly generating a _copy-assignment_ operator, which is what's actually being invoked here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler generated copy assignment operator is chosen by overload resolution:

```
class A{
public:
  A& operator=(A const& other){
    std::cout << "copy assignment\n";
    return *this;
  }
  template<class T>
  void operator=(T const& other){
    std::cout << "templated assignment\n";
  }
};
```

Will print "copy assignment" and is essentially equal to what the compiler will generate for you (without the printing, of course).

Comment: I knew that an operator= was being synthesized by the compiler. The implicit question was: is there a way to force it to use my operator= template?

Comment: You can define the others as private and empty so they aren't used.

Comment: @ildjarn: Nope, overload resolution will still choose the private one and trigger an access / deleted error. Access checking is not done during overload resolution, only afterwards.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: No, atleast not as far as I know.

Comment: @Xeo : Ah, you're right. Somehow I seem to forget that tidbit every few months. :-P

Comment: @LorenzoPistone : If that's what you _really_ want (which I find questionable), you could explicitly define your copy-assignment operator in terms of the templated assignment operator.